# How do I get the child controls of a ListBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, listbox

I have a ListBox in xaml which has a sub-ListBox inside the top-level ListBox's item template. Because the sub-ListBox is multi-select, and I can't bind the SelectedItems of the sub-ListBox to a viewmodel property for some reason, I'm trying to do a lot of this in the view code-behind.

I have everything working, except for one snag: I want to select all items in each sub-ListBox by default. Since the SelectedItems aren't data-bound, I'm trying to do it manually in code whenever a SelectionChanged event fires on the top-level ListBox. The problem is that I don't know how to get from the top-level ListBox to the sub-ListBox of the top-level selected item. I think I need to use the visual tree, but I don't know how to even get the dependency object that corresponds to the selected item.

Here's the code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Stuff}" SelectionChanged="StuffListBox_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedStuff, Mode=TwoWay}" telerik:RadDockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerik:RadDockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" telerik:RadDockPanel.Dock="Top" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubStuff}" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="SubStuffListBox_SelectionChanged" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StuffToSubStuffVisibilityConverter}}" telerik:RadDockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </telerik:RadDockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The converter ensures that only the selected top-level item has a visible sub-ListBox, and that's working.

I need to implement the following method:

```
private void StuffListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox stuffListBox = (ListBox)sender;

    foreach (Stuff stuff in e.AddedItems)
    {
        ...
        subStuffListBox.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

I tried doing `stuffListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(stuff)`, but that always returns null. Even `stuffListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0)` always returns null.

I also get strange behaviour from the selection changed method. '`e.AddedItems` will contain items, but `stuffListBox.SelectedItem` is always null. Am I missing something?

From what I've read, my problem is coming from the fact that the containers haven't been generated at the time that I'm getting a selection change event. I've seen workarounds that involve listening for a the item container generator's status changed event, but I'm working in Silverlight and don't have access to that event. Is what I'm doing just not possible in Silverlight due to the oversight of making SelectedItems on a ListBox read-only?

Comment: have you debugged this code.. ?

Comment: "can't bind the SelectedItems of the sub-ListBox to a viewmodel property for some reason" -- likely because the data context of the sub-listbox is the parent listbox, not the view (which has the view model as the data context, most likely).  Use `RelativeSource` to access the view model.

Comment: @PaulAbbott The problem with binding SelectedItems is that it is a read-only property, so I can't bind it to anything.

Comment: What about ContainerFromElement()?

Comment: @user2585308 that method doesn't exist on the ItemContainerGenerator or the ListBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you say this is probably best done in the ViewModel but you can select all the sub list items in code behind using VisualTreeHelper.

```
private void StuffListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var stuffListBox = (ListBox)sender;
        ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)stuffListBox.ContainerFromItem(stuffListBox.SelectedItem);
        ListBox sublist = FindVisualChild<ListBox>(item);
        sublist.SelectAll();
}
```

FindVisualChild Method as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
       DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
       if (child != null && child is childItem)
          return (childItem)child;
       else
       {
          childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
          if (childOfChild != null)
            return childOfChild;
       }
 }
 return null;
}
```

Comment: ListBox does not have a ContainerFromItem method.

Comment: does your ListBox have ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem? if not is your app WP8.1 or something else

Comment: Yes it does, but as I mentioned in my question, it always returns null on passing in source items.

Comment: Ive just tested the above code in a sliverlight app and it works. Selected Items of sub listbox selected. why are you using e.AddedItems? use stuffListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(stuffListBox.SelectedItem)

Comment: I also tried using stuffListBox.SelectedItem, but the SelectedItem is always null (even though a SelectionChange event fired because something had just been selected).

Comment: strange maybe something wrong with binding to viewmodel (if youre using one). Is SelectedStuff implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: It turns out that for a silly, complicated reason, I was wiping the items source for the stuffListBox, which cause the strange behaviour I was seeing with getting containers and the selected item.

With that out of the way, the above answer worked, with the caveat that I had to do something special the first time the top-level ListBoxItems loaded (using an event). That's because the ListBoxItems won't have been loaded yet the first time the selection change event fires. If anyone else has this problem, check your items source for bindings firing!

Comment: Ive had that problem many a time events, viewmodel commands etc changing collections. Excellent glad its fixed :)